# Codeigniter database loader sometimes doesn't load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue with codeigniter's database loader.

From time to time (5%) when reloading my webpage, I get this error :

```
    Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. 
    Filename: core/Loader.php

    Line Number: 232
```

But then I refresh the page and everything goes well.

It is a MySql database on a shared hosting. Anyone have encountered the same error?

Thanks!

Comment: it might just be that the shared host isn't so reliable and causes timeouts or something. as it's only refreshing that fixes it, and you're not changing anything.

Comment: Yeah that is what I think.

Comment: read reviews about the reliability of the host provider from people who have used it for some time, you should get something useful

Answer (score 2):

Buy better hosting. You don't have a problem with CodeIgniter's database loader but with database server. That's the only answer.

Comment: I do not think this is the issue, as it happened to me once on my local environment as well.